# How to delete a line in a file that contains only one specific character by using a bash script?

Tags: bash

I would like to delete all lines that contain a specific character. Even better would be to identify if there is a line containing (let's say a colon) only that character and then add that character to the next line or the line before, but I guess that's kind of complicated.

I have the following file (e.g.):

```
first line
second line
third line
;
```

Now I want to be like this:

```
first line
second line
third line;
```

Comment: You could use vi or sed

Comment: To delete a line that matches a pattern use :g/somechar/d

Comment: This is pretty broad. Can you offer some specific input/output examples and what you've attempted?

Comment: `man grep` for finding characters.

Comment: It sounds like your input file is colon-separated CSV but some of the fields might contain newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script just removes the lines:

```
#! /bin/bash
grep -v '^;$' "$1" > "$1".tmp
mv "$1".tmp "$1"
```

Call it like `name-of-script filename`.

Comment: That's pretty much what I wanted. But would be also possible to do the same with characters which have empty spaces (tabs) in front?

Comment: @Max Replace the first line of the script with `grep -v '^\s*;$' filename > filename.tmp`. That will handle ; characters which are preceded by whitespace and also ; characters which are not preceded by whitespace.

Comment: One more question: How could I apply that command to all files in a subdirectory?

Comment: Put those two commands in a script file (after you've added the standard `#! /bin/bash` script header line). Then type `name-of-script /path/to/subdirectory/*`

Comment: Hmm that doesn't really work for me. I guess the two commands have to be different then.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot something - I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, now it's working for files but I can't look through directories, even with `-r` it didn't work.

Comment: After playing around a bit I found out that this works:

`#! /bin/bash
find . -type f -name '*.<filetype>' -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    bash script $f
  done' sh {} +`